# Keep Data in TextBoxes like on pressing BACKSPACE

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, backspace

I want to keep some informations in some TextBoxes if I go back to this page programmatically. On Page1 I enter the informations and if I click on the button I redirect to the next page, but if an error is in the informations (like text in TextBox for numbers only) I want to go back by clicking on a linkbutton. I tried:

```
prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
LinkButton1.PostBackUrl = prevPage;
```

But if get back to the previous page all textboxes are empty. By pressing BACKSPACE on the keyboard, all informations stay kept.

How can I programatically do this to keep the informations like if I am pressing BACKSPACE ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this javascript on link button click

```
history.back()
```

**Example**

```
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so i have to do this in the .aspx file? Is there any way i can to this in the .cs file with a c# command?

This action also belongs to a passed variable from this previous page (if there was an error or not) so could u just show me how i can write this in the .aspx file with a if()? The URL is like error.aspx?=true or "false". In the c# i can handle this but i dont know how to do this in asp. I am a beginner xD

Comment: @user1879409 - yes you have to try in aspx only...not in code behind file...this is good way to do it

Comment: Is there any way i can to this in the .cs file with a c# command? This action also belongs to a passed variable from this previous page (if there was an error or not) so could u just show me how i can write this in the .aspx file with a if()? The URL is like error.aspx?=true or "false". In the c# i can handle this but i dont know how to do this in asp. I am a beginner xD